# How can I use SQL Server JSON_VALUE function in EF 6 Code First for classic .NET

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, entity-framework, dbfunctions

How can I use SQL Server JSON_VALUE function in EF 6 Code First for classic .NET? I found I can do it in **EF Core** like this:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static string JsonValue(string column, [NotParameterized] string path)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

// In OnModelCreating
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(JsonExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(JsonExtensions.JsonValue)))
    .HasName("JSON_VALUE")
    .HasSchema("");

// And then the usage
var result = db.Blogs.Select(t => JsonExtensions.JsonValue(t.Log, "$.JsonPropertyName")).ToArray();
```

But how can I achieve this in EF 6 in classic .NET (in my case, its 4.6.1)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In classic .NET it's a little bit different, but still possible like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new RegisterJsonValueFunctionConvention());
}

// Than define your function
[DbFunction("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema", "JSON_VALUE")]
public static string JsonValue(string expression, string path)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Then, because JSON_VALUE is not defined in the Entity Framework SQL Server provider manifest, you have to create IStoreModelConvention like this:

```
public class RegisterJsonValueFunctionConvention : IStoreModelConvention<EdmModel>
{
    public void Apply(EdmModel item, DbModel model)
    {
        var expressionParameter = FunctionParameter.Create("expression", GetStorePrimitiveType(model, PrimitiveTypeKind.String), ParameterMode.In);
        var pathParameter = FunctionParameter.Create("path", GetStorePrimitiveType(model, PrimitiveTypeKind.String), ParameterMode.In);
        var returnValue = FunctionParameter.Create("result", GetStorePrimitiveType(model, PrimitiveTypeKind.String), ParameterMode.ReturnValue);
        CreateAndAddFunction(item, "JSON_VALUE", new[] { expressionParameter, pathParameter }, new[] { returnValue });
    }

    protected EdmFunction CreateAndAddFunction(EdmModel item, string name, IList<FunctionParameter> parameters, IList<FunctionParameter> returnValues)
    {
        var payload = new EdmFunctionPayload { StoreFunctionName = name, Parameters = parameters, ReturnParameters = returnValues, Schema =  GetDefaultSchema(item), IsBuiltIn = true };
        var function = EdmFunction.Create(name, GetDefaultNamespace(item), item.DataSpace, payload, null);
        item.AddItem(function);
        return function;
    }

    protected EdmType GetStorePrimitiveType(DbModel model, PrimitiveTypeKind typeKind)
    {
        return model.ProviderManifest.GetStoreType(TypeUsage.CreateDefaultTypeUsage(PrimitiveType.GetEdmPrimitiveType(typeKind))).EdmType;
    }

    protected string GetDefaultNamespace(EdmModel layerModel)
    {
        return layerModel.GlobalItems.OfType<EdmType>().Select(t => t.NamespaceName).Distinct().Single();
    }

    protected string GetDefaultSchema(EdmModel layerModel)
    {
        return layerModel.Container.EntitySets.Select(s => s.Schema).Distinct().SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't about .NET Core or "classic" .NET. EF Core can run on both runtimes

Comment: Can you show an example of how are you using this? I'm having trouble setting the expression parameter value.

Comment: Have you managed to solve your problem? Sorry, I have no more example code and DB, would have to create it from scratch.

Comment: @walkerbox has spelled it all out perfectly.  Example on how to use it.  Assumptions:  The static method `JsonValue` is in some sort of global namespace.  The column containing JSON is named "Json" in your EF model.
`context.MyTable.Select(row => JsonValue(row.Json, "$.MyJsonSelector")`

Comment: @walkerbox thank you so much for the detailed steps. But I am running into problem where I need to convert (or cast) string to different data type like for e.g., BIT. How can I achieve CAST(JSON_VALUE(json, "$.MyJsonSelector") as bit)? Thank you in advance for pointing me in some direction to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it works with Entity-Framework 6, but probably worth mentioning [Impatient](https://github.com/tuespetre/Impatient/).

It Allows you to perform LINQ queries on `json_value` columns and more.

Comment: I don't suppose you have an example. I've been sifting through the docs and tests and am struggling to find one